# CAST or CONVERT: invalid attributes specified for type 'bit'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

i am making app in asp.net core 5.0 with EF.
Following LINQ query is executing:

```
var response = EntityContext.Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role).ThenInclude(x => x.RolePermissions).ThenInclude(x => x.Permission)
                    .Where(x => x.Email == email && x.IsVerified && x.IsActive).SingleOrDefault();
```

In SQL profiler this SQL is generated:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[UserId], [t].[Email], [t].[FirstName], [t].[IsActive], [t].[IsVerified], [t].[LastName], [t].[Password], [t].[Salt], [t1].[UserId], [t1].[RoleId], [t1].[RoleId0], [t1].[Description], [t1].[Name], [t1].[RoleId1], [t1].[PermissionId], [t1].[PermissionId0], [t1].[Description0], [t1].[Name0]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(2) [u].[UserId], [u].[Email], [u].[FirstName], [u].[IsActive], [u].[IsVerified], [u].[LastName], [u].[Password], [u].[Salt]
    FROM [User] AS [u]
    WHERE (([u].[Email] = @__email_0) AND ([u].[IsVerified] = CAST(1 AS bit(1)))) AND ([u].[IsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit(1)))
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [u0].[UserId], [u0].[RoleId], [r].[RoleId] AS [RoleId0], [r].[Description], [r].[Name], [t0].[RoleId] AS [RoleId1], [t0].[PermissionId], [t0].[PermissionId0], [t0].[Description] AS [Description0], [t0].[Name] AS [Name0]
    FROM [UserRole] AS [u0]
    INNER JOIN [Role] AS [r] ON [u0].[RoleId] = [r].[RoleId]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [r0].[RoleId], [r0].[PermissionId], [p].[PermissionId] AS [PermissionId0], [p].[Description], [p].[Name]
        FROM [RolePermission] AS [r0]
        INNER JOIN [Permission] AS [p] ON [r0].[PermissionId] = [p].[PermissionId]
    ) AS [t0] ON [r].[RoleId] = [t0].[RoleId]
) AS [t1] ON [t].[UserId] = [t1].[UserId]
ORDER BY [t].[UserId], [t1].[UserId], [t1].[RoleId], [t1].[RoleId0], [t1].[RoleId1], [t1].[PermissionId], [t1].[PermissionId0]',N'@__email_0 varchar(50)',@__email_0='string'
```

System returns following error:
**CAST or CONVERT: invalid attributes specified for type 'bit'**

Please help if you can
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened.

Before:

```
[Column(TypeName = "bit(1)")]
        [Required]
        [DefaultValue("true")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

After:

```
[Column(TypeName = "bit")]
        [Required]
        [DefaultValue("true")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

This was in user object and it makes trouble.
Now it works fine.